# Need to reload page to use link_to_add_fields in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

unable to load _contact_fields.html for the first time . i can work on adding fields only when i refresh the page.

application_helper.rb

```
   def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
      new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :contacts do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'contact_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Fields", f, :contacts %>
```

_contact_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset class="field">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Contact_Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Contact_Email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Contact_Phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  </div>
      <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Additional_Info %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :additional_info %>
  </div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "Remove Field", "#", class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

participants.js.coffee

```
    jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).closest('.field').remove()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

contact.rb

```
belongs_to :participant,:foreign_key => 'participant_id'
```

participant.rb

```
 has_many :contacts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, allow_destroy: true
```

For the first time when i click on link_to_add_fields # is passed as shown below http://localhost:3000/participants/new# if i refresh the same path after removing the # the i am able to add fields .

Comment: even i too stuck in the same situation.. i too need the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using turbolinks? This could be happening because Turbolinks is loading the page, and there isn't a document ready event being fired. You want to wait until Turbolinks fires the page:load event.

To fix this, you can adjust your javascript to the following:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .remove_fields', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  $(this).closest('.field').remove()

$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
```

*You do not need the jQuery -> with the above code.*

Comment: Ya I am using turbo links i have changed my jquery script to the code which u have sent . Thank You so much .. Its working fine ..